# How to enable hardware acceleration for the Android emulator in Mac OS?

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I am trying to use the Intel x86 Atom images (along with the Intel HAXM Accelerator), but not sure how to turn on hardware acceleration in Mac OS?

Each time I run my app in the emulator, it exits as soon as it starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install it from the Intel site: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x